# Is it possible to have a scalar and vector part for an equation

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, triangles

**Question:** The median AD of the $\bigtriangleup$ABC is bisected at E, BE meets AC in F, then AF: AC is equal to.

**Answer:** The correct option is $\textbf{A} \frac{1}{3}$.

Taking A as the origin let the position vectors of B and C be $\overrightarrow{b}$ and $\overrightarrow{c}$ respectively.

Equations of lines BF and AC are $\overrightarrow{r} = \overrightarrow{b} + \lambda(\frac{\overrightarrow{b}+\overrightarrow{c}}{4}-\overrightarrow{b})$ and $\overrightarrow{r} = \overrightarrow{0} + \mu\overrightarrow{c}$ respectively.

For the point of intersection F, we have:

$\overrightarrow{b}+\lambda(\frac{\overrightarrow{c}-3\overrightarrow{b}}{4})=\mu \overrightarrow{c}$

$\implies 1-\frac{3\lambda}{4}=0$ and $\frac{\lambda}{4}=\mu$

$\implies \lambda=\frac{4}{3}$ and $\mu=\frac{1}{3}$

Therefore, the position vector of $\overrightarrow{F}$ is $\overrightarrow{r} = \frac{1}{3}\overrightarrow{c}$

Now, $\overrightarrow{AF} = \frac{\overrightarrow{c}}{3} \implies \overrightarrow{AF} = \frac{1}{3}\overrightarrow{AC}$

Hence, $AF : AC=\frac{1}{3}:1=\frac{1}{3}$

Comment: You need to surround math expressions by dollar signs.

Comment: Readers on this site prefer for the question to be completely contained within the post (unless specifically referring to a particular concept/discussion), meaning they shouldn't have to open any links to understand the full context.

Comment: I guess you misread the equation (which is bad written in the picture). The correct one should be $\vec{b} + \lambda\left(\frac{\vec{c} - 3\vec{b}}{4}\right) = \mu\vec{c}$. And the next equalitis follow immediately.

Comment: @TonyMathew I'll try next time. Thanks for letting me know

Comment: @AntonioDeAngelis . I misread the question.Also I was thinking of representing $\vec{b}$ and $\vec{c}$ in terms of $\hat{i}$,$\hat{j}$,$\hat{k}$. Thanks

Comment: @Dremus is the line equation correct now?

Comment: @Desperado So, the equation for BF is that you wrote out?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to have a scalar and vector part for an equation, like so: $\lambda \overrightarrow{v}, \lambda \in \mathbb{R}$